# How can I resolve the redirect php problem?

Tags: php, html, redirect, header, location

After clicking on Login button does not appear the index page, I tried something like:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

and

```
header('Refresh: 2; URL=index.php', true, 301);
```

but without result

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("include/config.php"); 

If($_POST["submit_enter"])
{
    $login=$_POST["input_login"];
    $pass=$_POST["input_pass"];
}
if($login && $pass)
{
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *FROM admin WHERE login='$login' AND pass='$pass'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['auth_admin']='yes_auth';
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        $msgerror="Nume de utilizator si/sau parola incorecte";
    }
}else{
    $msgerror="Introduceti numele de administrator si parola";
}
include("include/head.php");  
?>

<div id="block-pass-login">
<?php
    if($msgerror)
    {
        echo'<p id="msgerror">'.$msgerror.'</p><hr>';
    }
?>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Autenficare</h3>
    <form method="post">
        <ul id="pass-login">
        <li><label>Nume</label><input type="text" name="input_login"/></li>
        <li><label>Parola</label><input type="password" name="input_pass"/></li>
        </ul>
        <p style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" name="submit_enter" id="submit_enter" value="Logare"/></p>
    </form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include("include/config.php");
if($_SESSION['auth_admin']=='yes_auth'){

    if(isset($_GET["logout"])){
        unset($_SESSION['auth_admin']);
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }

    $title="Acces la BD";
    $_SESSION['urlpage']="<a href='index.php'>Acasa</a>";
    include("include/head.php");
?>
    <div id="block-body">
<?php
    include("include/header.php");

    $query1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Categorie WHERE tip='mare'");
    $result1=mysqli_num_rows($query1);

    $query2=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Categorie WHERE tip='munte'");
    $result2=mysqli_num_rows($query2);

    $query3=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Destinatie WHERE Tip_Destinatie='mare'");
    $result3=mysqli_num_rows($query3);

    $query4=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Destinatie WHERE Tip_Destinatie='munte'");
    $result4=mysqli_num_rows($query4);

    $query5=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Destinatie_Hotel");
    $result5=mysqli_num_rows($query5);

    $query6=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Hotel WHERE Tip_Destinatie='mare'");
    $result6=mysqli_num_rows($query6);

    $query7=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Tip_Transport WHERE Denumire='avia'");
    $result7=mysqli_num_rows($query7);

    $query8=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Tip_Transport WHERE Denumire='auto'");
    $result8=mysqli_num_rows($query8);

    $query9=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Destinatie_Transport WHERE Denumire_Tip='avia'");
    $result9=mysqli_num_rows($query9);        

    $query10=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Destinatie_Transport WHERE Denumire_Tip='auto'");
    $result10=mysqli_num_rows($query10);

    $query11=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Categorie WHERE tip='tratament'");
    $result11=mysqli_num_rows($query11);

    $query12=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Destinatie WHERE Tip_Destinatie='tratament'");
    $result12=mysqli_num_rows($query12);

    $query13=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Hotel WHERE Tip_Destinatie='munte'");
    $result13=mysqli_num_rows($query13);

    $query14=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Destinatie_Shopping");
    $result14=mysqli_num_rows($query14);

    $query15=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Shopping");
    $result15=mysqli_num_rows($query15);

    $query16=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Hotel WHERE Tip_Destinatie='tratament'");
    $result16=mysqli_num_rows($query16);

    $query17=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Destinatie_Excursii");
    $result17=mysqli_num_rows($query17);

    $query18=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Excursii");
    $result18=mysqli_num_rows($query18);



?>
    <div id="block-content">
        <div id="block-parameters">
        <p id="title-page">Statistica generala</p>
        </div>
        <ul id="general-statistics">
        <li><p>Tari | mare<span><?php echo $result1;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Destinatii | mare<span><?php echo $result3;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Hotele | mare<span><?php echo $result6;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Tari | munte<span><?php echo $result2;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Destinatii | munte<span><?php echo $result4;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Hotele | munte<span><?php echo $result13;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Tari | tratament<span><?php echo $result11;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Destinatii | tratament<span><?php echo $result12;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Hotele | tratament<span><?php echo $result16;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Tari | avia<span><?php echo $result7;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Destinatii | avia<span><?php echo $result9;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Tari | auto<span><?php echo $result8;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Destinatii | auto<span><?php echo $result10;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Tari | Shopping<span><?php echo $result14;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Destinatii | Shopping<span><?php echo $result15;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Tari | Excursii<span><?php echo $result17;?></span></p></li>
        <li><p>Destinatii | Excursii<span><?php echo $result18;?></span></p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}else{
    header("Location:login.php");
}
?>
```

**EDITED**
[var_dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qYF5.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you do `var_dump($result);` and add that result to your question?

Comment: do you also use a redirect in your index.php? because in the printscreen you showed it seems there is an infinite redirect?

Comment: I deleted the redirect from index.php and now I can log in but the page is empty

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['auth_admin']);`

Comment: did you put session_start() in index.php as i suggested?

Comment: Yes, I put session_start() in index.php

Comment: string(8) "yes_auth" appears this after var_dump

Comment: this means you have other problems as well, check the php error log

Answer (score 1):

1) Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, always escape user input! Please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

2) It seems you are storing passwords in plain text in your database, this is very bad, go and learn about hashing. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

I am missing a `session_start()` in your index.php that could cause the infinite loop i am not sure.

Comment: Sad to see this kind of code is still produced in 2018. Let's hope this 'developer' will fix it.